# Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null in laravel when redirecting

Tags: javascript, laravel

After authentication when i want to redirect to dashboard it shows blank page and showing this error in console

```
VM2842:277 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null
    at <anonymous>:277:41
```

My code is

```
<body>
    <section id="container" class="">
      @if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
          @include('admin.header.header')
          @include('admin.sidebar.sidebar')
          @yield('content')
      @else
          @yield('content')
      @endif

    </section>

     <!-- javascripts -->
  {!!Html::script('js/jquery.js')!!}
```

As i already include script within body

Comment: This code seems like a partent view, I would like to see the child that is extending it (the one with the section called 'content')

Comment: console.log(document.getElementById("blue")); it returns null what should i do now

Answer (score 0):

My script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function waitForLoad(id, callback){
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.getElementById(id)){
            clearInterval(timer);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

waitForLoad("subm", function(){
    console.log("load successful, you can proceed!!");
    document.getElementById("subm").onclick = function()
    {
        alert("I got clicked");
    }
});

</script>
```